# no .sln file in c# project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, csproj, solution

I want to open a project in `Visual Studio 2012` and I am looking at the source folder, but it does not have a solution file. The project looks like a class library project and it has one `.csproj` file and everything else is `.cs` files.

I am not sure how to open this project.

*Any suggestions?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Double-click the .csproj file. Visual Studio will open the project file, regardless if it's not part of solution. A solution is not mandatory.

Comment: To clarify further, Solutions in Visual Studio can be made of multiple projects. A .csproj file indidicates it's a project using the C# language. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfzh36t7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Additionally, when you open the project a solution is automatically created in memory. If you attempt to "Save All" VStudio will prompt you to save the solution to disk.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft has provided tool called SlnGen. You can use it to generate the solution file. It’s very simple to install and use. It works pretty well with multiple projects as well. Once the sln file is generated, you can open the project(s) using this sln file.

**Installation**: open command prompt and run the below command.

```
dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlnGen.Tool
```

Command to generate the sln file.

```
slngen --launch:false --folders:true --collapsefolders:true --solutiondir:src --solutionfile:MySolution.sln --ignoreMainProject --verbosity:normal **.csproj
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://microsoft.github.io/slngen/) and GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/slngen).

Answer (score 0):

When there is no .csproj file and you have like "adduser.aspx.cs" files, Open VS->File->open->Website options and the from there browse to your folder and open the folder that opens your solution and you can run the project.